# How to symbolize that figure is cropped?

Tags: masters, thesis, graphics

I need to add a photo with some additional data drawn over it to my thesis in computer science. But the photo is large and I want to crop bottom half of it. But then it could be misleading, that there is a part of the image missing.

I will write it to the image description, but I want it to be obvious at first sight without reading the description. Is there some standard way to display that part of the figure is cropped?

Comment: Standards are likely to vary across disciplines. You should probably specify yours.

Comment: True. I've edited the question, it's computer science.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is shown in biology/biochemistry journals by a solid border around the cropped image. This is fine to do only if, like you say, you are not removing meaningful data or hiding potential confounding results. If in doubt, ask your advisor.

Answer (score 2):

What kind of a figure is that? If it is a plot, and you want to zoom in to a particular range of it, then you may want to include full plot, then a zoomed in one. For the latter, you may mention that "plot of y from x{a to b}" in the caption. Plus, it would be much better if you say a few lines about why this particular range is important to be emphasized this way, in between your text.

This is not a symbolization, but an effective one to crop something out of a drawing. Thus, I'd prefer this if I were to read your thesis.

Comment: It's not a plot, it's photo with some additional data drawn over it.

Comment: Then I suggest the previously suggested way of doing it: Draw a visible rectangle on the area you are going to crop it; then write a few lines of reasoning behind the importance of this particular area, then put the cropped version with appropriate captions.

Answer (score 0):

You can show it is cropped by having a lined/**dashed border** around the edges this will show that it is cropped.